# Reading/Writing /Executing .xlsm files in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, openpyxl, pyodbc

I have been working on a project where I am supposed to use Python for data analysis. I am stuck on one part in the project. Actually, I want to copy all the data from a table in SQL server to an Excel file with a .xlsm extension. I have written most of the code using pandas and pyodbc libraries. However, I learned that pandas doesn't support .xlsm extension so switched to openpyxl, which supposedly does. However, my code doesn't work.

Here are the relevant lines of code:

```py
sql_table = 'table1'

sql_query = f'SELECT * FROM {sql_table};'

        # Read the processed data in SQL Server
processed_data = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, conn_sql)

data = pd.DataFrame(processed_data)

wb = load_workbook('new.xlsm')

ws = wb['Internal']

for r in dataframe_to_rows(data, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

wb.save('new.xlsm')
```

I am sure about the modules I have imported, the SQL connection and other stuff. This block of code is the only problem. Do note that I want to access an already existing Excel file with a .xlsm extension and not create a new one.

Expectation:

The script runs without an error and I see the changes in the relevant Excel file.

Reality:

I receive an error which states:

> ValueError: Unable to read Workbook: could not read worksheets from new.xlsm.
> This is most probably because the workbook source files contain some invalid XML.

Comment: "This is most probably because the workbook source files contain some invalid XML" - so can you open the file manually?

Comment: So I can still open the file. It is just a duplicate of the original file.

Comment: You might wanna actually include which line gives the error and / or the whole stacktrace. This is like watching a movie with 30 minutes cutoff at the beginning

Comment: _It is just a duplicate of the original file._ What does that actually mean? Did you use Excel to "Save as" the file to a new one with a .xlsm extension, or did you just duplicate the file in Explorer and rename the extension to .xlsm?

Comment: Another thing to consider is that Office products often take out exclusive locks on files while they have them open, which can prevent other processes from opening them to read. Have you closed all Excel windows that might have the files open?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, yes I did take care of this. I encountered this issue some time ago and it usually shows up in the terminal when you run the script if the file is open because it says, 'Permission Denied'

Answer (score 0):

As pandas states in the [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) documentation

> Supports xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlsb, odf, ods and odt file extensions read from a local filesystem or URL.

So one way to do it is, opening the xlsm file with pandas read_excel, concatenating the two frames and then overwriting the file.

I have not tried it but something similar to this should work

```
sql_table = 'table1'

sql_query = f'SELECT * FROM {sql_table};'

        # Read the processed data in SQL Server
processed_data = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, conn_sql)

data = pd.DataFrame(processed_data)

ws = pd.read_excel('new.xlsm', sheet_name='Internal')

ws = pd.concat([ws, data])

ws.to_excel('new.xlsm')
```